# Determine type of first argument in a call to strcpy(): (char *) vs char[]

Tags: types, static, arguments, analysis, strcpy

I have been given a C program with about 20.000 calls to the
library function strcpy. In the program, the type of the first argument
(the destination buffer) passed to strcpy is declared sometimes as a
(char *), sometimes as a char[]. Actually my job is to find all occurrences
of the strcpy() where the first argument is declared as a pointer to char
(and then return the result of the search to my supervisor, for example,
as a list [filename; line number]). Obviously I could accomplish this job
by examining every single call to strcpy by eye, but it could take a
whole week. Since I cannot afford this I would be grateful if someone
knows a way to automize this search (a tool or even a programming trick).
Thanks to all in advance.